Why is my new M4 MacBook Pro not detecting older USB hub?
For a long time I've been using a M1 Mac mini with a KVM switch, which also serves as a small USB hub.
I just got a new M4 MacBook Pro. When I connect the new computer to the switch, it detects the monitors fine but not the USB hub. The hub does not show up in the USB panel of System Information at all. The USB ports on the MacBook Pro work fine when connected directly to my iPhone or to an external hard drive I have. I played around with the "Allow Accessories to Connect" settings, as that seemed to help with problems people were having on this a few months ago, but it did not help me.
One thing to note is that the USB ports on the KVM hub are all USB-A, as are some of the devices I'm plugging into it. I have the KVM hub connected to the mini on an A-to-A connection. It shows up in the System Information on the mini as being connected to a "USB 3.0 bus", and the KVM appears below that as a "USB 2.1 Hub." The cable I'm using to connect the KVM hub to the MacBook Pro is an Anker A-to-C cable that's worked fine in other contexts. On the MacBook Pro, all I see in System Information are three "USB 3.1 Bus" connections.
Is it possible that this is a backwards compatibility issue?

I looks to me like your KVM switch is not following the USB spec.  This is my clue:

One thing to note is that the USB ports on the KVM hub are all USB-A, as are some of the devices I'm plugging into it. I have the KVM hub connected to the mini on an A-to-A connection.

USB A-to-A cables should not be used for connecting to peripherals.  There is a provision in the USB spec for A-to-A cables, and I'll include an image for how it is wired from the USB spec.

You should notice that VBUS is not connected, that means a standard cable will not provide power.  I would gather from your description that the A-to-A cable that came with your KVM switch has VBUS connected so the KVM switch can get power from the Mac Mini.
Under the USB spec a USB-A port is not to be a power input, only power output.  USB-C can provide power or receive power, with some important details in the spec on how the transfer of power is negotiated.  By using an A-to-C cable that follows the spec (which I assume Anker is likely to provide to consumers) there's no power from the Mac Mini to the KVM switch.  USB A-to-A cables that have VBUS connected could short circuit a computer's power supply and damage hardware, to the point of being a fire hazard, if someone used this cable outside of its intended purpose.
If I'm correct on the problem then I see one of two solutions.
The first solution I offer, and the one I recommend highly, is to dispose of this KVM switch and get a new one that follows the USB spec.  That A-to-A cable is a fire hazard, take a wire cutter to it and cut it in half so if someone finds it they don't break something by using it.  Take a hammer and bust up the KVM switch so it is obviously unusable then recycle the remains.
The second solution I offer is to use an adapter with a female USB-A on one end and male USB-C on the other to connect the A-to-A cable that came with the KVM switch to the Mac Mini.  That non-standard cable is wired for the non-standard KVM, by replacing the cable with one that follows the USB spec the power and data wires are not connected as they should for the KVM to communicate to the computer.
I hope this has been clear enough on what is going on.  To describe the problem fully could get deep into how the USB spec works.  The point is that the KVM switch is not following the USB spec and so you can't use standard cables to connect to it.  I focused on the power part as that is what poses a hazard to hardware, the data connection is also messed up so even if the KVM switch gets power elsewhere there will still not be a working data connection.  Or at least no working USB 2.0 data, the non-standard cable and KVM port might allow for USB 3.0 data but keyboards and mice are USB 2.0 devices.
I will note that I included the image from the USB spec for those that will want to fight me on how USB A-to-A cables are supposed to be wired.  I've had that fight before and I clipped that bit out of the spec to hopefully avoid having that fight again.
